# Create database for face recognition issue

Tags: python, opencv

I took some photos of me and after that I want to use them for training my neural network. When I checked if the photos was correctly taken I used `cv2.imread` and after that I displayed one of them on the screen and the following error appeared.

> (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow

I have checked if the path was good and tried again, same error.

This is the code that i used for taking pictures:

```
  cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


  face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
  face_left = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_profileface.xml')

  # For each person, enter one numeric face id
  face_id = input('\n Enter your face id:  ')



while(True):

   ret, img = cam.read() 
   gray = img 
   faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
   face2 = face_left.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
   gray = cv2.flip(gray, +1)
     for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w + 50, y + h + 50), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        count += 1 
        cropFace = gray.copy()        
        cv2.imwrite("D:/poze/photo0"  + str(count) + ".jpg",cropFace) 

   k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff 
   if k == 27:
      break
   elif count >= 450: # Capture 450 face pictures
      break
```

And when I tried to show the image this is the code that I used:

```
    import cv2
    path="D:/poze/photo01.jpg"
    show_img = cv2.imread(path)

    cv2.imshow("img",show_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: What is the filename of the photo you are trying to open? Is it actually a .jpg file? Can you open it in a program outside of OpenCV?

Comment: Yes, it' s a jpg file and i can open outside of OpenCV

Answer (score 1):

The error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 means it was not able to read your image. The size is not > 0.

Your image path is:

```
"path../photo0"  + str(count) + ".jpg"
```

However, you are showing this file:

```
"path../photo01"
```

Thus, add the extension ".jpg" when you display the image.

Comment: i've added the extension and still the same issue appear

Comment: then check if you have a fie in this folder (path).

Comment: i have checked and the file exists

Comment: then copy the location of the file and paste it in here.  path="<dir>/photo01.jpg". Btw, do not use parenthesis when assigning to path. It becomes a tuple. it should be a string.

Comment: try using double slash:  path="D://poze//photo01.jpg"

Comment: I wish I can control your machine.. :)